# Pgfplots fails to generate boxplots for some data set

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, debugging

I use `pgfplots` to generate boxplots, however with some small data sets as the following, I get an error message.

```
 speed
    2
    3
    1
    2
    2
    11
```

Here is the error message :

```
Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-floating point number `'. The unreadable part was near ''
```

To avoid this problem, I need to add white noise to my data set when generating it, but it is only a dirty workaroud. Do you know how to avoid the pgfplots error message ?

You can for example try the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
speed
2
3
1
2
2
11
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[boxplot] table[y index=0]{test.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably report this bug to the maintainer of PGFPlots, Christian Feuersänger.

Comment: This is done, bug reported.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report.

Comment: Does anyone know if this bug has been fixed? I can't find a bug report on it at [http://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/)